# Connector between SF Marketing Cloud and SF Commerce Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, commerce-cloud

Can anyone tell me more about connecting SF Marketing Cloud and SF Commerce Cloud platforms. What uses Cases can we implement other than sending email for abandoned baskets.

Any documentation would be welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Code and documentation can be found at: https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/marketing-cloud-connector

**Note**: You'll need to [follow instructions here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/b2c-developer-resources-and-tools/b2c-developer-access-repositories) in order to access the Salesforce Commerce Cloud GitHub repositories.

There's also a Solution Kit related to the marketing cloud connector on Trailblazer community at: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.icx_b2c_transactionalemail_parent.htm&type=5&d=7010M000001yv8PQAQ (but beware, it is somewhat out of date)

See below for the maintainer's comments about the connector.

---

EDIT by maintainer: The cartridge implements Marketing Cloud's collect.js which enables site analytics, and is necessary for you to move to the next step regarding getting abandonment features enabled. You would need to contact Marketing Cloud's Services team to have abandoned cart, abandoned browse, and/or abandoned search enabled. Marketing Cloud itself is quite versatile, so how you react to those events is up to you. You can create journeys within Marketing Cloud that work to recover lost sales due to abandoned cart/browse/search, or if you have some other scenario that you want to trigger within Marketing Cloud in reaction to such events, that should be achievable.

The cartridge was built from Commerce Cloud perspective to enable integration into Marketing Cloud, so it's best that you contact your Marketing Cloud representative to get recommendations for how best to use features such as abandonment events. They'll be much more well versed in Marketing Cloud's abilities, and should be able to assist you with any setup and configuration required within Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Looks like the GITHUB link is not working now, Do you have a new one?

Comment: The Github link is private for members of the Salesforce Commerce Cloud developer community. You need a Salesforce Commerce Cloud Account Manager Credential, 2-factor auth, and you need to tie the Account Manager credential to your GitHub ID. See: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/b2c-developer-resources-and-tools/b2c-developer-access-repositories

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the most recent solutions kit Salesforce released for MC,Commerce and Service Cloud. These include:

- Abandonment Cart
- Coupon redemption
- Order on behalf
- Transactional email
- View order hisotry and cancel order
- Personalised Marketing recommendations solutions

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cross_cloud_marketing_commerce.htm&type=5